# set width between two knobs in ionic 2 dual range slider

Tags: ionic2

```
<ion-range dual-knobs="true" pin="true" min="0" max="100" step="3" snaps="true"></ion-range>
```

I want the above code to be looked like shown in image

[image]

Comment: you mean default value of the knob or the tick width?

Comment: default value of the knob

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/range/Range/),

> Setting the dualKnobs property to true on the range component will
>   enable two knobs on the range. If the range has two knobs, the value
>   will be an object containing two properties: lower and upper.

Use `ngModel`

```
<ion-range dual-knobs="true" pin="true" min="0" max="100" step="3" [(ngModel)]="knobValues" snaps="true"></ion-range>
```

In your component:

```
knobValues:{
  upper:100,
  lower:50
}
```